# Linking - which library is included?

Tags: linker

The gcc man page says, *"Order does matter when you use several options of the same kind; for example, if you specify `-L` more than once, the directories are searched in the order specified."*

However, are these `-L` directories searched before the system directories (e.g., those that `ld` normally uses)?

I have the case that I have two libraries of the same name, one in a system location and another in my working directory, and I want to use mine, but cannot figure out how to verify my version is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "ldd /bin/your/application". E.g:

```
ldd `which bash`
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff46eda000)
libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007facdd618000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007facdd414000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007facdd090000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007facdd863000)
```

In general there are 3 options how one can specify which library to use for your binary:

1. Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable before starting your executable
2. RPATH linker option (see other my questions/answers on SO to find out more about this option)
3. Add your shared library to all other system libraries.

Comment: Very helpful binary!  Is there a way to do ensure this within my Makefile?

Comment: @gnucom: Yes, you can use ldd from Makefile. Albeit If this will be a good idea depends from your project.

Comment: what I mean is there a way to ensure my included directories are searched before the system's, as opposed to checking what libraries were included afterwards?

Comment: @gnucom. Now I see what you mean. Here is a very good explanation about linking http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html. Also see my updated answer.